# MVC Ajax.BeginForm InsertionMode

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-ajax

Web Config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true"/>
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
```

JavaScript referenced files:

```
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/modernizr-1.7.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js") type="text/javascript"></script>
```

CSHTML page:

```
@using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions { UpdateTargetId = "result", LoadingElementId = "progress", InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace }))
{
    <div class="form">
        <div class="emailBox">
            <input id="email" name="email">
            <input type="submit" value="Join Us">
        </div>

        <div id="result">
        </div>
        <div id="progress" style="display:none;">
            <img src= "@Url.Content("~/Content/images/Ajax-loader-bar.gif") ">
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Controller.cs:

```
    [HttpPost]
    public string Index(SignUpModel model)
    {
        return "Hello";
    }
```

What's the reason when i click on the SUBMIT button, the entire page gets replace with a white page that says "hello". I was under the impression that Ajax.BeginForm would replace the content of the **DIV RESULT**.

What am I doing wrong??

Also, the LoadingElementID
Would it HIDE automatically  when the AJAX call will return its value?

=========================
**ANSWER**
Firebug showed that one of the Referenced JS files was NOT FOUND.
After I fixed that ..it all worked as expected.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure that you have `jquery`, `Jquery.unobtrusive-ajax` script files added on your page where you are using `Ajax.BeginForm`. Furthermore, check in firebug (or any debugger tool) for presence of javascript errors that might be causing ajax to fail and triggering full post back of the entire page. And yes, the loadingelement should hide automatically when the result of ajax post comes back.
Also make sure that your web.config contains following setting

```
<appSettings>
        <add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true"/>
    </appSettings>
```

Comment: I have Jquery and Jquery.unobtrusive-ajax. Where can I find the Jquery.unobstrusive file ?

Comment: Updated Question stating the files i have. Where can I find any missing file?

Comment: Sorry, i was mixing jquery-unobtrusive-validation file. But it is not required here.

Answer (score 1):

1) make sure you include post in your header

```
   @using (Ajax.BeginForm(new AjaxOptions 
{ UpdateTargetId = "result", 
LoadingElementId = "progress", 
InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,   
HttpMethod = "POST"  }))
```

2) Make sure you include all of the referenced JavaScript files on your page

instead of returning hello try to return View()

Comment: Ideally i want to return different messages based on the value provided on the textbox.

Comment: i think you are miising some reference files

Comment: Can u please explain a bit more that "return view" instead?

Comment: It should render in the view you are in but in you case i think what you use in return is fine